Airline compensation regulation (EC) No 261/2004: Crowdstrike related case law search
EasyJet cancelled a flight from Copenhagen to Basel. A passenger filled a claim related to the cancellation, but Easyjet rejected it, citing the Crowdstrike event as "extraordinary circumstances"
So far as I know, the issue has not been decided by the courts. Is there some way to search EU rulings on this topic?
Specifically I wanted to know whether the courts have ruled on Crowdstrike related matters about whether the Airline can treat this as extraordinary circumstances. Basically to search precedent or case law on this in EU what's a good site?
These things should be in the public domain I assume?
Even if not established case law I am curious to find if there any ongoing cases specifically related to denied compensation from Crowdstrike.
Another question: do judgements in one EU country act as precedent in another or not at all?
PS. Related question about this issue:
https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/190861/46933

EU law is a civil law legal system so there are no binding precedents.

... but e.g. Dutch courts do use judgements from other EU countries as jurisprudence in subject areas where the EU is competent. Also, the Van Gend and Loos case established direct effect where the ECJ decision does bind national courts.

@MSalters what decides which subject areas the EU is "competent" in.

@curious_cat: The EU treaty.
